# android sqlite update error

Tags: android

I am writing an application which will access an sqlite database for reading and writing.
I have created the database using sqlite database browser and pushed it to /data/local/tmp.
It will be used by other apps as well and must exist on the system even if my app doesn't
My app can read the database given the full path but I cannot update the database.
My manifest is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.intralot.settings"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/my_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="....."
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The messages in LogCat are:

```
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 4002): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/local/tmp/settings.db
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 4002): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/data/local/tmp/settings.db-journal, db=/data/local/tmp/settings.db
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 4002): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = statement aborts at 20: [UPDATE settings SET ip=? WHERE _id=1] , db=/data/local/tmp/settings.db
```

The code that triggers this is:

```
try{
    result = db.update(SETTINGS_TABLE, newValues, "_id="+index, null);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions for the database file in /data/local/tmp? Perhaps it is not readable/writeable. But anyway, why not put the file on the external storage?

Comment: @dermatthias maybe for security reason(s) :)

Comment: @dermatthias as Sajmon said, the sd will be used for other purposes. Permissions are rw for all.

Answer (score 0):

By default the database directory is

```
/data/data/{packagename.app.name}/databases
```

You will not access other directories in `/data`. You could gain access with root and executing shell code. Which I don't believe is optimal.

Comment: I still need the database present even if the app is not installed. Maybe I could try to update the database as a shell command issued by my app